# Cypress: Running different file in the cypress-cucumber

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have one project where I have implemented the `cucumber framework`. but when I run the `HubActivity1.feature` file it will be using `ProjectProfile.spec.js` instead of `HubActivity1.spec.js`.

I don't know why this happening. please let me know if anyone has any ideas. Maybe it's my mistake anywhere. Please suggest me.

Please check out the below image of what is happening in my test.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your configuration of cucumber is correct:

1. Check if on your `cypress.config.ts` you have the specPattern path specified for example:

`specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.{feature,features}'`

and you import in correct way plugin with the same file:

```
  setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const options = {
        ...browserify.defaultOptions,
        typescript: require.resolve('typescript'),
      };
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber(options));
    },
```

2. Check if you have specified the correct path configuration in nonGlobalStepBaseDir to your step definition in the file package.json:

   `"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": { "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true, "nonGlobalStepBaseDir": "cypress/step_definitions", "commonPath": "./common" },`

Comment: I have not used typescript in my project. can you please try to reproduce issue from my repo `https://github.com/VaghasiyaKrupal/cucumber-issue.git`

Comment: In my opinion, you have too many function declarations in steppers with the same name. It seems to me that each function name should be different. it is about:   `Given Verify profile page and cookies` This name has more then one implemented function with this name and can't find correct url